# Android Scroll View is Too Long

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-scrollview

I'm super new to Android -

I've dropped in a scrollview on my screen and am just placing some text inside of it. I'm doing this because on some phones the text runs off the screen.

The problem I'm having is that the scrollview I've dropped onto the page is longer than the content it holds -- the more narrow the phone screen is, the longer the scrollview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="20"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
        android:text="Get ready to melt fat and burn calories with Fit Body Boot Camp&apos;s 14 Day Fat Furnace Workout Program! This is a detailed 14 Day Workout plan based on Fit Body Boot Camp&apos;s Unstoppable Fitness Formula that has been implemented in close to 300 boot camps worldwide by hundreds of thousands of clients who made the decision to lose weight and get healthier."
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textColorLink="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </EditText>
```

There are some more edittexts after this one, but this is the gist of it. Let me know if you see something stupid.

Comment: can you give a screenshot of how it looks in your phone or simulator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your background is in the linear layout that is in the ScrollView.
If you put the scroll view in another linear layout that is parent to the ScrollView and contains the background and remove the background from the Linear layout that is a child to the Scroll View the issue will be solved.

**It will look like this:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/app_background" >
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="20"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
    android:text="THE LONG TEXT YOU'VE TYPED"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textColorLink="#FFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think scrollview should fill the parent, and children views wrap content since layout_height is the size that the view will actually have on the screen, the scrolling thing happens inside the view

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    //...
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    //...
>
```

**EDIT**
as pointed out by dbalaouras better use "match_parent" instead of "fill_parent" since the latter is deprecated. The result is the same, just the name has been changed just because "fill" was confusing, if you set that it won't fill the remaining space but just set the dimension according to its parent

Comment: Better use "match_parent" instead. fill_parent "is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by match_parent" (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: @lelloman I changed the scrollview to match_parent and its children to wrap content, but it didn't change anything. The added length seems to come from the linear layout, as when I delete it, the screen length returns to normal. BTW I see the added length in eclipse, not just on the emulator.

Comment: @lelloman the problem seems to be that I had a repeating background asset and when it repeated it extended the screen a good amount. I'll just make a smaller tiling background so that it won't extend so far. 

Shouldn't there be a way to make it not extend the screen though?

Comment: this sounds really weird, the exceeding size of linearlayout should be managed by the scrollview, it doesn't matter how big is the child view, the scrollview (with layout_height="match_parent") can't be bigger than the screen...even if you set layout_height="10000px" to the linearlayout, the scrollview should match the parent's height anyway...where is your background set? to the child linearlayout?

Comment: @user2051879 btw are you using layout_WIDTH = "match_parent" for linearlayout?

Comment: Yeah, the background was set on the linear layout -- I changed it to the scrollview and it resolved the problem.

I am using layout_width with linear layout; it's redundant to specify a width I suppose, when it should automatically span the screen width?

Comment: @user2051879 I think that specifying both width and height in xml layout is mandatory. however since the problem is solved consider to accept the answer ^^